# Handlebars link-to helper with Bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I found a post on here that said in order to use Twitter Bootstrap's navbar with Ember and Handlebars, so that the `<li>` gains the 'active' class automatically, I could do this:

```
    {{#link-to 'dashboard' tagName="li" href=false}}
        {{#link-to 'dashboard'}}
            Dashboard
        {{/link-to}}
    {{/link-to}}
```

It works, however, I've just enabled Ember's LOG_TRANSITIONS and it shows me that the views are getting transitioned to twice for the links in the navbar.

How do I correctly render the navbar list with Handlebars and avoid this double loading?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you have two `link-to`'s for `dashboard` route.

You have two options:

Use the link-to just in the `li` tag:

```
{{#link-to 'dashboard' tagName="li" href=false}}
    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
{{/link-to}}
```

Use `bubbles=false` in the inner link-to:

```
{{#link-to 'dashboard' tagName="li" href=false}}
    {{#link-to 'dashboard' bubbles=false}}
        Dashboard
    {{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

So the event isn't propagated.

Comment: Thanks. Both of these solutions seem to work also on iPad, but first one is cleaner. Before this I had a workaround with <a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}> but that isn't working on iPad.